# Spider and snake in a square

Tags: identify-this-game

In the game you were a spider which could run from one wall to the other.
The snake could either destroy your net or you.

If you reached another wall the room where snake could move got smaller. If said room was small enough you beat the level.

[image: New version of it]

It looked like that this seems to be a [mobile rework](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tarantula-vs-snake/id483584037)

Comment: Basically it's a derivative of the 1981 arcade game 'Qix' then.

Comment: With Qix, you went to the next level as soon as you claimed more than half of the play space. You got points proportional to the claimed area, so a big part of advanced game play was building out narrow walls, and then luring the Qix into a confined space that you could quickly close off, thereby claiming a much larger than 50% portion with a single stroke.

Comment: Yo, pretty cool nickname!

Comment: Maybe check if the screenshots for any of the games in the MobyGames [QIX Variants](https://www.mobygames.com/game-group/qix-variants) group look familiar?

Answer (score 4):

From the description it could have been [Xonix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xonix). Difficult to say without knowing the platform.

Comment: Yes i was exactly a xonix like game. I don't remember the platform. It could be mac or windows arround win 95 - 98